# force update/sync of subscribed (url) calendar in google calendar with google app script

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have a url of a calendar `https://longurl.ics` that I successfully subscribed into google calendar. My issue is that sometimes, it takes a few days to synchronize events from the url calendar to google.

Is there a way to force the update with google app scripts?... I've beeen looking into the documentation and the web with no luck so far...

Comment: When you say you want to update the calendar, do you mean as if you refresh the page? to see the currently active events? Also, what do you mean when you say subscribing the url to the calendar? what is your overall intention with the code?

Comment: Hello, In google calendar you can suscribe to an external calendar via url. So events in this external calendar appear in google calendar in its own individual calendar. Google seems to update/sync the info of that calendar into google calendar once a day, but sometimes it doesn't. What I want is to force that updata/sync (i.e. read the external calendar info) on a specific time...

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I see what you mean, you want to force that sync between the two different calendars. Are they both Google Calendars by the way? if so, a script could easily help with getting all the events from one to the other. If that's not the case, what are you using?

Comment: Hello, I'm syncing with office calendar (work). I do not have a code yet because I even haven't found a command that allows me to do what i want.

Comment: @kurokirasama I’ve found in the [documentation to subscribe to calendars](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100?hl=en&ref_topic=1672445) that it takes about 12 hours for syncing with the linked external calendar. However, if you’re still experiencing longer waits I would suggest you open a direct GSuite support case, which you can do [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Comment: cool, thanks! Yes, I also read that it should sync every 12 hours or so... But I don't have a Gsuite account xD T_T

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found this library on github that does exactly what i needed. I already have it running :D

[GAS-ICS-Sync](https://github.com/derekantrican/GAS-ICS-Sync)

Comment: was about to write my own until i found this. surprised nobodys has made a chrome extension or something to do this